# jQuery .get() returning old JSON array even with $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a few forms on a page which I'm submitting using AJAX and then in the `success` function I hide the container div, use `.get()` to get the new JSON array with the info I need and display it in the container div, then show it again.

My problem is that `.get()` is getting the old data from before the form was submitted (and the form submits successfully and the database is changed), even though I already have `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});` in the beginning of the JS file.

Unfortunately I can't post my code because I signed a non-disclosure agreement.

Comment: Can't you just post a snippet of the code? I don't see how posting a genericised AJAX request showing your logic would break an NDA. I also don't see why you need to use `get()` in an AJAX request.

Comment: Have you checked the server code?

Comment: @skAstro the problem is not server based as the json does change when i see the array in the page where it's posted. the array i see in the console when i use .get() just isn't the updated array

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the form is submitted to one url and the array i need is on another url

Comment: That just makes it even more confusing, and still isn't relevant to the use of `get()`. We really need to see your code to help you.

Comment: Does the AJaX call include a random parameter in the request string? Try adding one if not. Also, you can do tests on a sample page that does not include any of the `secret` code, but reflects the problem you are facing, and then share that dummy code.

Comment: @MarcCompte "Does the AJaX call include a random parameter in the request string" what do you mean by request string?

Comment: @SuzanneEdelmanCreoconcept you should add some sort of timestamp in the request ?t=12315325 to avoid caching. Try this approach.

Comment: @SuzanneEdelmanCreoconcept With AJaX you are making an HTTP call to the server `http://server/folder/file`. If you go to the Network tab of your debugger you can see those calls. Do they include a random querystring parameter like this? `http://server/folder/file?random=187652748`

Comment: @MarcCompte it didn't, i added it, and now it doesn't return anything because it makes the url different and there's nothing on that url. what i did was $.get(url + "?t=" + new Date($.now()).getHours() + new Date($.now()).getMinutes() + new Date($.now()).getSeconds(), function(array) {//do stuff});

Comment: @MarcCompte the url doesn't end in a file, it ends with n=id where id is needed to display the correct information so if i add ?r=342112 it won't work

Comment: @SuzanneEdelmanCreoconcept if your URL already has parameters in it don't add `?t=`, you need to use `&t=`.